# JBoss vault.sh doesn't generate shared key

Tags: jboss, passwordvault

I'm trying to create a password vault for JBoss 6.1.1

First, I do:

```
keytool -genkey -alias vault -keystore passwords.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024 -storepass password -keypass password -dname "CN=DSA vault,OU=RIS,O=Company,L=City,ST=State,C=DE"
```

Then I call vault.sh in jboss/bin, enter all the values as requested and the output is this:

```
Secured attribute value has been stored in vault.
Please make note of the following:
********************************************
Vault Block:test
Attribute Name:encrypted
Configuration should be done as follows:
VAULT::test::encrypted::1
********************************************
```

when it should be somethin like this:

```
Please make note of the following:
********************************************
Vault Block:test
Attribute Name:encrypted
Shared Key:ZDc1Y2Q5Y2EtZGRjNC01YTU1LWJiOTgtYzcwODYyNTIzYjJkTElORV9CUkVBS2RzYXZhdWx0
Configuration should be done as follows:
VAULT::test::encrypted::ZDc1Y2Q5Y2EtZGRjNC01YTU1LWJiOTgtYzcwODYyNTIzYjJkTElORV9CUkVBS2RzYXZhdWx0
********************************************
```

So it doesnt generate a hash. I'm kinda stuck, have googled it, but found nothing. Cane someone point me in the right direction? Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

Got it myself:

The mechanism for the vault changed between the versions. The missing hash is expected behavior, there just needs to be the "1" as a placeholder.